# Making an IDL interface for a method which return an array

Tags: java, arrays, corba, idl

How to write IDL file for a method which return an float type array.  I understand a IDL file like following

```
module AdditionApp
{
  interface Addition
  {
    float add(in float x, in float y);
    oneway void shutdown();
  };
};
```

Here `add` method return a float type value. But how to write a IDL file for a program which has a method which returns a float type array?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a typedef in IDL, so it should be

```
module AdditionApp
{
  typedef float floatArray[5];
  interface Addition
  {
    floatArray add(in float x, in float y);
    oneway void shutdown();
  };
};
```

Do note that an Array has a predefined size. If you need a variable size you need to use

```
module AdditionApp
{
  typedef sequence<float> floatSeq;
  interface Addition
  {
    floatSeq add(in float x, in float y);
    oneway void shutdown();
  };
};
```

Comment: Your variable sized example appears to be the same as the first one.